# Springfox and Avro Generated Java Classes

Tags: java, swagger, avro, springfox

I have some java classes generated from an avro schema using the avro compiler. I'm using those in my Spring Rest controller and using `Springfox` to generate an openapi specification.  Because the generated avro classes have methods `getSchema()` and `getSpecificData()` those are showing up in the openapi model.

Is there a way to globally tell Springfox to *not* include certain named fields in classes?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using a plugin:

```
    @Bean
    public ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin removeAvroFieldsFromSwagger() {
        return new ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin() {
            @Override
            public void apply(ModelPropertyContext context) {
                if( context.getBeanPropertyDefinition().isPresent() ){
                    BeanPropertyDefinition definition = context.getBeanPropertyDefinition().get();
                    if( "schema".equals(definition.getName()) && definition.getPrimaryType().getTypeName().contains("org.apache.avro.Schema")){
                        context.getBuilder().isHidden(true);
                    }
                    else if( "specificData".equals(definition.getName()) && definition.getPrimaryType().getTypeName().contains("org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData")){
                        context.getBuilder().isHidden(true);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: this was the solution i was looking for, but i am getting duplicates for when my field is uppercase. it shows 1 in uppercase, and 1 in lowercase. Any solution for this?

Comment: I moved away from Avro but I didn't notice this.  Maybe you can put in specific overrides for those fields?